# How to do conditional insert when doing data migration using Scribe?

Tags: data-migration, scribe-workbench

Here is the case:

I have an SQL Database table that I want to migrate to a Dynamic CRM 4.0 database. There is a table (let's call it Table_A ) that have a particular column (Table_A.Type). I want to migrate the table A data into either the Account entities or Contact entities in Dynamic depending on the Table_A.Type. If the Type is 0, I'll put it into Contact, else if the Type is 1, I'll put it into Account.

How can I do this using the Scribe Workbench?

Answer (score 0):

The problem already solved. I use formula to put a condition in the migration flow.